# Is there any way that I can restrict a child class from inheriting some of its parent's methods?

Tags: python, inheritance, python-2.7

```
class Liquid(object):
    def foo(self):
        pass

    def bar(self):
        pass

class Water(Liquid):
```

Say, I have the two classes above, *Water* inherits from *Liquid*. Is there any way I can restrict Water from inheriting one of the parent's methods, say `bar()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sort of. But don't do it.

```
class Liquid(object):
    def foo(self):
        pass

    def bar(self):
        pass

class Water(Liquid):
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name == 'bar':
            raise AttributeError("'Water' object has no attribute 'bar'")

l = Liquid()
l.bar()
w = Water()
w.bar()
```

Comment: Interesting answer~ and yes, I would not do it~ still, good to know. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

You can override the method to be a no-op, but you can't remove it. Doing so would violate one of the core principles of object-oriented design, namely that any object that inherits from some parent should be able to be used anywhere the parent is used. This is known as the Liskov Substitution Principle.

Comment: I always go with overriding the method to a no-op. The piece of the framework that I am using, however, relies on the existence of the method to determine if a feature is available. But thanks for reminding me of the principle in OOD. I should dump this approach and find a different way out. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can, as the other answers, say, break one of the inherited methods.

The alternative is to refactor out the "optional" methods, and inherit from a baseclass that doesn't have them:

```
class BaseLiquid(object):
    def foo(self):
        pass

class Barised(object):
    def bar(self):
        pass

class Liquid(BaseLiquid, Barised): pass

class Water(BaseLiquid):
    def drip(self):
        pass
```

Comment: Good suggestion but not applicable in this case, whereas the parent class is part of the framework that I am using and normally I don't want not mess around with that.

Comment: @ahmoo Do check that this isn't possible (have a quick look at the source). Otherwise, do analyse whether this method is always required - you could have the overridden method raise an exception, or return fixed data.

Comment: Will do, sir. Thanks for the suggestions. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not a good idea, but you could always use metaclasses to implement private attributes:

```
def private_attrs(name, bases, attrs):
    def get_base_attrs(base):
        result = {}

        for deeper_base in base.mro()[1:]:
            result.update( get_base_attrs(deeper_base) )

        priv = []
        if "__private__" in base.__dict__:
            priv = base.__private__

        for attr in base.__dict__:
            if attr not in priv:
                result.update( {attr: base.__dict__[attr]} )

        return result


    final_attrs = {}
    for base in bases:
        final_attrs.update( get_base_attrs(base) )

    final_attrs.update(attrs)

    return type(name, (), final_attrs)


class Liquid(object):
    __metaclass__ = private_attrs
    __private__ = ['bar']
    def foo(self):
        pass

    def bar(self):
        pass

class Water(Liquid):
    __metaclass__ = private_attrs

print Water.foo
print Water.bar
```

Output is:

```
<unbound method Water.foo>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testing-inheritance.py", line 41, in <module>
    print Water.bar
AttributeError: type object 'Water' has no attribute 'bar'
```

EDIT: This will mess up isinstance() because it doesn't modify **bases** of the class.

Answer (score -1):

http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/slots.html

I suspect you can do this, by using the **slots** attr.

It might be possible implementing a **getattr** method and throwing the appropriate exception if bar is called.

However, I agree, you don't want to do this in practice, since its a sign of bad design.